# Kubernetes GKE with a persistent disk

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, unreal-engine4, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to setup our CI in a scalable way.
Currently, we have a Windows Server VM on GCE and Jenkins runs jobs on it from time to time.

However, as we'll add more jobs, we would like to have a scalable system.

There are some constraints though:

- there's lots of data synced from Perforce (p4) for the Engine (custom UE4 Engine). And then it was built (takes a while). This is rarely updated.
- there's lots of data synced from p4 for our product. Currently, every time we build, we do a new `p4 sync` to just retrieve the delta (takes a few seconds) since the last time. And we have a persistent disk. Retrieving the full data would take 45 min - 1 hour (not counting the lost bandwidth).

So, we're trying to use GKE. We would need to somehow:

- Every night (or so), `p4 sync` the build machine and create an "image" from it now that it contains the latest data.
- Have GKE use that newly created image.
- When we start a job, have it create a container using that image. This would contain data at most 24 hours old.
- this container would `p4 sync` what has changed during the day, execute whatever it needs to execute, then disappear into the abyss. Whatever generated data would be transient and not affect other containers.
- if several jobs run in parallel, they don't read/write from/to the same place.

So, this is the big-picture idea. There might be better ideas.

Right now, I'm not sure if:

- this is doable
- how to tackle this (if doable)

Regards,

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Regarding updates for your image, you may use the [Build Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds) feature to construct your image after changes are pushed to the build source. Keep in mind that Cloud Build only supports Cloud Source Repository, GitHub, or Bitbucket. Unfortunately, I could find Perforce plugins for GKE build systems.

Here’s a couple of articles using Jenkins and Github; [article1](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automated-build-images-with-jenkins-kubernetes), [article2](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-kubernetes-engine), for automated image builds.